# CSS Image Flip on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am stumped at this and hoping someone can help.

I have a page background which is done in HTML and shows off a client's Instagram photos. Using this plugin: justifiedgrid.com

The client would really like the images to flip on page load like this http://www.starworksartists.com/hair/adir-abergel/instagram/

I have tried adding CSS to the images like so

```
.jig-loaded  img {
    transition: 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.1) !important;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will need some JS wizardy. You could always inspect their code to get some ideas.

Comment: What's your html doctype? Can we get an example of your html? An html snippet should improve the answer we can provide.

Comment: I am sure it can be done with pure CSS :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use css keyframe animation:

```css
img {
  -webkit-animation: flip 1s;
  animation: flip 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(90deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(90deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png?s=128&g=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be set the initial state of the images to the transformed version, apply a `transition` to it as well, and then use JavaScript to add a class that sets the transform back to the "normal" state (not transformed).

This way it's easy to keep track of states and you can toggle between the two states with no jumping in between. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9edvhkr/1/) (the `onload` is handled by JSFiddle in the demo - you'll need to add it yourself in your code)

Otherwise you could use a keyframe animation on load with `animation-direction:forwards` that the goes from the transformed state to the non-transformed state. If all you're doing is an effect on the initial page load it is fine, but if it's to be any more interactive you should use `transition`s instead.